# Почему не работает nginx?

Tags: nginx, openserver

Зашёл в файл Nginx_1.19_vhost.conf и добавил вот такой код

```
location ~* /static/\d+/ {
   alias /static;
}
```

На фронте у меня есть путь к css вот такой: /static/main.css
Подключаю я его вот так /static/738337/main.css но почему-то он не хочет подключаться, пишет, что файл не найден. Что не так?

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете регулярное выражение `/static/\d+/` для матчинга URL, но не добавляете соответствующее число в URL для подключения статических файлов. Регулярное выражение ищет пути, начинающиеся с `/static/`, за которым следует одна или более цифр, и заканчивающиеся слэшем. Вам нужно добавить в URL число, которое соответствует регулярному выражению.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/738337/main.css">
```

Если у вас есть путь со статикой, которая находится в другом месте, необходимо изменить путь в конфигурационном файле nginx. Для этого найдите `location` и изменить путь в директиве `alias`:

```
location ~* /static/\d+/ {
   alias /path/to/static;
}
```

`/path/to/static` замените на путь к вашей директории со статикой.

Comment: Так я такой же линк добавил он не работает